# Apiary change format to cURL sample

Tags: curl, apiblueprint, apiary

please advise. I have a problem with the cURL format in the Apiary documentation.

I insert array to **+Body**

```
+ Body
            [
                'command' => 'domain-list'
            ]
```

and the sample will generate for me

```
--data-binary "[
    \'command\' => \'domain-list\'
]"
```

but for PHP endpoint of our application I need to receive data in *$ _POS*T as an *array*.

The functional shape that works for me is generated by [Postman](https://www.postman.com)

```
--form 'command = "domain-list"'
```

It is a change of the *--data-binary* parameter to *--form* so that Apiary uses this notation to generate a cURL sample.

PS: The PHP sample generates this correctly

```
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
                 'command' => 'domain-list'
             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apiary doesn't parse your body to get info that is array. All is string for template. Just copy paste into template content of body, this isn't smart template.

Not sure if it is helps.

Comment: Finally, I modified the endpoint in the application. Thank you